# Unable to send pandas dataframe object to SQL when using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am transforming a single dataframe using multiple cpu cores and want to insert the result into MySQL.

Using the below code I observed only one active cpu core and no updates to MySQL. No error messages were produced.

The original dataframe `pandas_df` is never altered. All transformations to `pandas_df` are stored in `result_df`.

The code has been verified to work correctly in serial.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(MYSQL_STRING)

def function(pandas_df, tuple, engine):
    #slice and dice pandas_df according to tuple
    result_df.to_sql("TABLE_NAME", engine, if_exists='append')


pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
for tuple in tuples:
    pool.apply_async(est, args=(pandas_df, tuple, engine))
```

Most of the tutorials and guides I came across only passed strings inside `args=()`. 
There are however articles that do demonstrate the ability to pass numpy arrays: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html

I have also tried the above code using the `map_async()` method and/or inserting a `return` statement inside the `function` and there was no difference in behaviour.

I am open to trying different python modules. I need a solution which transforms a single dataframe in parallel and inserts the result into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the function has access to all the variables otherwise a silent failure may occur.